# Troubleshooting /bin/login failure with double free error

Tags: login

I did some upgrades yesterday on my 14.04 machine and now I can not get logged in with either GUI or /bin/login.

When I run a single user shell as root and execute `/bin/login pechter`, I get

```
/bin/login double free or corruption (fasttop) 0x00000000024ad990
```

When I try

```
export MALLOC_CHECK_=0 /bin/login pechter
```

I get my normal shell and it works with my account as the login and the root account.

Here's the end of the strace:

```
open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 10
lseek(10, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0
fstat(10, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1126, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1126, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 10, 0) = 0x7f0a1dd00000
lseek(10, 1126, SEEK_SET)               = 1126
fstat(10, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1126, ...}) = 0
munmap(0x7f0a1dd00000, 1126)            = 0
close(10)                               = 0
setgroups(8, [1000, 4, 24, 27, 30, 46, 108, 124]) = 0
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 10
writev(10, [{"*** Error in `", 14}, {"/bin/login", 10}, {"': ", 3}, {"double free or corruption (fastt"..., 35}, {": 0x", 4}, {"000000000137a760", 16}, {" ***\n", 5}], 7*** Error in `/bin/login': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000137a760 ***
) = 87
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0a1dd00000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
tgkill(1288, 1288, SIGABRT)             = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1288, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT +++
```

Any suggestions of where to take this to figure out what I screwed up.
Never seen this one before...

I know enough to grab the `strace` output on `/bin/login` but that's about it.

The whole strace is too long to post... a lot of `ENOENT` stuff when running at single user but no other EWHATEVERs...

I grep'd the `ENOENT` stuff below since the whole trace was too long.

Any thoughts?

```
pechter@S20:/tmp$ cat /tmp/x
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/run/utmpx", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/run/utmpx", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ffe7a74cc30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffe7a74cc30)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_winbind.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/security/pam_winbind.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/tls/x86_64/libsamba-util.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe7a74c010) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/tls/libsamba-util.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/tls", 0x7ffe7a74c010) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/x86_64/libsamba-util.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/x86_64", 0x7ffe7a74c010) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-util.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libwbclient.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-credentials.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libndr.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbconf.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libpdb.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgensec.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtalloc.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libbsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtevent.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtevent.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-hostconfig.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-hostconfig.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libkrb5.so.26", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libkrb5.so.26", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldb.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldb.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcom_err.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcom_err.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgssapi.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgssapi.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libndr-standard.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libndr-standard.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libndr-nbt.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libndr-nbt.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtevent-util.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtevent-util.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtdb.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtdb.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/liblber-2.4.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/liblber-2.4.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbldap.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbldap.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamdb.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamdb.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsasl2.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsasl2.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libndr-krb5pac.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libndr-krb5pac.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libndr-krb5pac.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgcrypt.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgcrypt.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgcrypt.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgnutls.so.28", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgnutls.so.28", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgnutls.so.28", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libasn1.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libasn1.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libasn1.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libntdb.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libntdb.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libntdb.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libwind.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libwind.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libheimbase.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libheimbase.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhx509.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhx509.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsqlite3.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsqlite3.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhcrypto.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhcrypto.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libroken.so.18", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libroken.so.18", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libheimntlm.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libheimntlm.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgnutls.so.26", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgnutls.so.26", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgpg-error.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgpg-error.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgpg-error.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libp11-kit.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libp11-kit.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libp11-kit.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtasn1.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtasn1.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtasn1.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libnettle.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libnettle.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libnettle.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhogweed.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhogweed.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhogweed.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgmp.so.10", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgmp.so.10", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgmp.so.10", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libffi.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libffi.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libffi.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_ecryptfs.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/security/pam_ecryptfs.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_ck_connector.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/security/pam_ck_connector.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/run/nologin", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/nologin", O_RDONLY)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/samba/private/secrets.ntdb", 0x7ffe7a74d580) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/samba/private/passdb.ntdb", 0x7ffe7a74d320) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/samba/account_policy.ntdb", 0x7ffe7a74ccf0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/run/samba/winbindd", 0x7ffe7a749d50) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/samba/group_mapping.ntdb", 0x7ffe7a74d150) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/samba/group_mapping.ldb", 0x7ffe7a74d2d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/var/run/samba/winbindd", 0x7ffe7a749cf0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/pechter/.hushlogin", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/log/wtmpx", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/motd", O_RDONLY)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(10, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(10, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/run/utmpx", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/run/utmpx", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(10, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/proc/vz", F_OK)                = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(10, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 33) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: What error do you get if you try to log in as a normal user from the command line (not GUI)? If logging in as root works, try creating a new user and attempting to log in as that user. If that works, we know the issue is specific to your existing user. Please [edit] your question with the results of the above tests.

Comment: Maybe post also the md5 sum of your `/bin/login`, someone might compare it to their `/bin/login` md5 sum and exclude the corruption. Can't post mine right now unfortunately as I'm not on Ubuntu.

Comment: That is from the command line... MD5sum checks against two other Ubuntu 14.04 boxes.  Temporary fix is a shell script /bin/login that sets MALLOC_CHECK_=0 and exports it and then execs /bin/login -- otherwise the only way into the machine was single user boot.

Comment: Getting the same double free in lightdm as well....

Comment: Did you try as a different user? It seems very strange that it works for `root`.